# Installing NuGet packages to custom folder in a project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with many projects.  For one of the projects I would like the files from NuGet to download to a specific folder in my project.  For example, I intend to use Bootstrap and also Signalr.  I would like Bootstrap to download everything into one folder in my application, and not create folders within my project root.  For example, I have a folder called 'Libs' in the project and would like those libraries to use 'Libs' as their root folder.  This is due to an external build solution that handles everything in the 'Libs' folder.

I've found [these docs](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.1) about using a NuGet.config folder for the solution, but this does not handle my problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible. Each Nuget package is written with specific instructions on how to install into a project. One of those instructions is where to put files, another example would be what transform to apply to the `web.config`. Nuget doesn't specify a way to modify these instructions. The only thing you could do would be to modify the packages yourself - download the `.nupkg` file and open it up as a zip file, you will be able to edit the folder structure from there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I appreciate the suggestion of modifying the .nupkg file, but am concerned that if I (or someone else) updates the project libraries via NuGet then they'll be back to their original location and not the modified location via NuGet?  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you would have to modify it every time.