# Install nuget package to different folder for one project within solution

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a VS solution with multiple projects, and I'm using Nuget to obtain external references. However, it's important that the package files for one project Not be in the same folder as the packages for the rest of the solution. As such I would like to put them into their own, seperate folder.

It would also be acceptable if all of the packages went into one folder, and then only the ones used by other projects were copied into the folder that they need them to be in. But I don't know of any way to achieve this behavior either.

If it helps, the specific scenario is a Unity project referencing a standard .NET class library project. The solution contains the .csproj file for the library DLL and also the ones generate by Unity. Because unity regenerates those project files every time the Unity project is changed, any packages to be used by those projects need to be inside the Unity project's Assets/ folder, or else the references won't be added to the generated .csproj files.

However, ALL dlls contained anywhere in the Assets/ folder are added to the generated projects, unless manually marked as not to include on a per-file basis. Which is why I don't want the packages referenced by the Library project to end up in that folder, as manually going through and marking every single .dll in every single package not to be used by the Unity project will become very tedious very fast. Especially since some packages download numerous dlls for many different versions of .net.

Comment: Is it similar to this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231293/installing-nuget-packages-to-custom-folder-in-a-project-in-visual-studio-2015, you want to install it to a custom folder for one project.

Comment: I think that question is asking about controlling the folder structure the package sets up for itself, as well as what directory it's installed into. I only care about the later, not the former.